# how to leave from chrome pdf viewer page in kios mode

Tags: kiosk-mode

i'm using chrome kiosk mode. When i open pdf it's open in chrome pdf viewer but i cant leave this page wihout keyboard. so user stucking on this page. how to fix this? maybe there is a way to make button "home" at top of site in chrome?